# ASP.Net MVC Merge resources from assembly with external resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I have an assembly containing all the resources logically structured
using convention over configuration.

```
[My.Resources]
 - [Controller]
    - [View]
        - Strings.resx
        - Strings.fr.resx
        - Strings.nl.resx
 - [Controller]
    - [View]
        - Strings.resx
        - Strings.fr.resx
        - Strings.nl.resx
    - [View]
        - Strings.resx
        - Strings.fr.resx
        - Strings.nl.resx
...
```

I'm looking for a way to auto-merge external resources (custom csv or resx files)
with the existing resources at runtime.
Preferably from the same assembly using a dedicated folder.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of the ResourceManager and then use its CreateFileBasedResourceManager() method to read the resources from the external .resx file.

Comment: That was my first idea but I wonder how I can merge with the file based resources and provide the resource as is..?